# PHP Write string to new line for the first time and not at the end of file

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using Codeigniter function `write_file()`, I can write to an existing file like this:

```
write_file("path_to_file", "String four"."\n", "a+");
```

Assume I already have a file like this:

```
String one
String two
String three
```

With `write_file("path_to_file", "String four"."\n", "a+")` , I have the ouput below when writing to file for the first time:

```
String one
String two
String three String four
```

Any idea about how I can write **String four**  to new line for the first time? Like shown below:

```
String one
String two
String three 
String four
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could first check if the file is empty; if it is, just write the line. If it's not, append a new line and your content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not knowing much about this write_file() function, but given what you said, this should work :

```
write_file("path_to_file", "\n"."String four"."\n", "a+")
```

Comment: No need to concatenate the strings in the second parameter when you use double quotes: `"\nString four\n"`.

Comment: @samitny, you are right but in this case, concatination is handy to make the code more readable. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: More readable, maybe, even if a lot of IDE highligth these '\n' most of the time. But the solution without the concatenation is ~35% faster than the other one.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding new line before String four:

```
write_file("path_to_file", "\nString four\n", "a+")
```

Comment: You might want to look at why the existing last line (String three) is _missing_ the newline \n it should have. If it were properly written, with \n, you wouldn't have to do special tricks with String four.