# Writing an email list (txt file) with codeigniter to import in mailchimp

Tags: php, codeigniter, mailchimp

I want to generate an email list from all the users in my database.

I followed this guide http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/helpers/file_helper.html

Also I tried this: [PHP Write string to new line for the first time and not at the end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322558/php-write-string-to-new-line-for-the-first-time-and-not-at-the-end-of-file)

I already got users from my database, this is what I have in my controller:

```
public function maak_lijst_bezoekers(){

    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->model("Lijst_bezoekers_model");
    $data = $this->Lijst_bezoekers_model->get_all_bezoekers();

    foreach($data as $d){
        if ( ! write_file('./uploads/lijst_bezoekers_mails/lijst_mails.txt', $d['naam']." ".$d['voornaam']." ".$d['email']."\r\n"))
        {
            echo 'Unable to write the file';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'File written!';
        }
    }

}
```

The get_all_bezoekers function returns an array like this:

```
 return $bezoekers->result_array();
```

I have 2 users in this database but only one line and one user is in the text file.

Can someone please give me some tips on how to get a whole list into a txt file with codeigniter, so I can **import it into mailchimp**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
if ( ! write_file('./uploads/lijst_bezoekers_mails/lijst_mails.txt', $d['naam']." ".$d['voornaam']." ".$d['email']."\r\n"))
```

to

```
if ( ! write_file("./uploads/lijst_bezoekers_mails/lijst_mails.txt", $d['naam']." ".$d['voornaam']." ".$d['email']."\r\n", "a+"))
```

Notice the "a+" as the last parameter of the write_file function. Please refer to the [Codeigniter documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/helpers/file_helper.html) and [PHP fopen Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) - the modes section.

Without this change of mode, you are basically starting writing the file from scratch on each iteration instead of appending to it.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer it helped. I did watch the PHP documentation about the modes section before but I guess I didn't understand how it worked.